# Google chart local json file loading issue

Tags: javascript, html, json, charts, google-visualization

I am new to google chart. I tried to load a json data file but somehow my script does not recognize it. 
First, I got this code, which works fine.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- EXTERNAL LIBS-->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <!-- EXAMPLE SCRIPT -->
    <script>

      // onload callback
      function drawChart() {

        var public_key = 'dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W';

        // JSONP request
        var jsonData = $.ajax({
          url: 'https://data.sparkfun.com/output/' + public_key + '.json',
          //This json local file is in the same directory of this html file. It was downloaded from the sparkfun.
          //url: 'stream_dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W.json'
          data: {page: 1},
          dataType: 'json',
        }).done(function (results) {
          var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
          console.log(data);
          data.addColumn('datetime', 'Time');
          data.addColumn('number', 'Temp');

          $.each(results, function (i, row) {
            data.addRow([
              (new Date(row.timestamp)),
               parseFloat(row.tempf),
            ]);
          });
          var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));

          chart.draw(data, {
            title: 'Wimp Weather Station'
          });

        });

      }

      // load chart lib
      google.load('visualization', '1', {
        packages: ['corechart']
      });

      // call drawChart once google charts is loaded
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 100%;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

But, if I uncomment the line "url:stream-...." and comment the line "url:'https://data...", the script somehow does not work. It must be the same json file but depending on "url", the code does not work. I don't know how to resolve this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks perfectly alright.There could two possible solutions:

1. I would check for the ',' after the URL link.
2. You could also try using the getJSON and process the file contents in the callback function:

Which would be :

```
$.getJSON(stream_dZ4EVmE8yGCRGx5XRX1W + '.json', function(obj) {

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));

  chart.draw(data, {title: 'Wimp Weather Station'});

});
```

Comment: Solution 1: web link was working. My problem is related to the local file json calling.   Solution2: I tried this, but I still have the same problem.... It seems the local json file cannot be found.... but I am not sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

Probably it occurs since `json` file could not be handled when it stored on your server.

If you are using *IIS*, then add MIME Type for JSON file type:

```
Extension: .json
MIME type: application/json
```

Follow [Add a MIME Type (IIS 7)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725608%28v=ws.10%29.aspx?f=255) for a more details.

If you are using *IIS Express*, the following example demonstrates how to configure MIME Type for JSON (`web.config` excerpt):

```
<system.webServer> 
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```